# Is there a Javascript lexer / tokenizer (in PHP)?

Tags: php, javascript, lexer, tokenize

I've seen a couple of Python Javascript tokenizers and a cryptic document on Mozilla.org about a Javascript Lexer but can't find any Javascript tokenizers for PHP specifically. Are there any?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with either, so I can't tell you anything about what they do and in what detail they tokenize code into, but I can see two:

- [JSLint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/docs/running_from_your_php_website.htm) is an executable but comes with a PHP interface - probably not enough for you, as it probably doesn't publish the raw tokenization to the calling program
- [PHPSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected) claims to come with a full Javascript tokenizer that you can maybe tap into. This looks the most interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Javascript for PHP5
http://j4p5.sourceforge.net/
(It's an older project, but IIRC had a pretty complete tokenizer.)

Answer (score 2):

[JSMin+](http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/cat/716) a javascript minify implementation in PHP which includes a JSTokenizer.

It used [Narcissus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_%28JavaScript_engine%29) from Mozilla as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

[jTokenizer / jParser](http://timwhitlock.info/blog/2009/11/jparser-and-jtokenizer-released/). jTokenizer mimics the PHP tokenizer. jParser generates a parse tree, which can be traversed and manipulated.